# Routing packets to different available networks using process' pid / uid

Tags: networking, process, routing, pid

I need to route packets from some processes(unique pids/uids) to desired network connection.

So, Suppose we have 4 processes with pids 10, 11, 12, 13 respectively; and we have two network connections eth0, eth1.

How can we make sure that the packets from process ids 10 & 11 are routed through eth0 while packets from process ids 12 & 13 are routed through eth1 ?

Comment: What OS are you talking about?

Comment: my OS is Ubuntu 11.04 Linux Kernel 2.6.38

Comment: Check this question please http://serverfault.com/questions/128357/routing-application-traffic-through-specific-interface/128374#128374

Comment: Check this question please: http://serverfault.com/questions/128357/routing-application-traffic-through-specific-interface/128374#128374